# Object to JSON serialization inside thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is there a way in thymeleaf to output json of an object from the context. I can do it inside the controller but don't really want to.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/{projectId}/edit")
public String editProject(Model model, @PathVariable Long projectId) {
    Project project = projectRepo.findOne(projectId);
    // Below line works, but I want to put the object to the model
    // model.addAttribute("project", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(project));
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    return "project/edit";
}
```

Partial Template:

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            project: [(${project})]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thymeleaf does this out of the box, I think you just need to add `th:inline="javascript"`.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            project: /*[[${project}]]*/ {}
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats great. Works without the semicolon after {}

Comment: This isn't JSON. It's Javascript. When sending JSON (`<script type="application/json" th:inline="javascript">`) Thymeleaf will wrap names and values between single quotes, where the `JSON.parse` method from clients require double quotes.